# Only showing part of string

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string

This may sound a bit strange but I'm trying to only show part of a string that is retrieved. The string that is retrieved contains something only the lines of NAME:myname and I'm trying to only show the "myname" part is there a way to 'disect' a string considering I know what the prefix "NAME:" is all ways going to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of ways:

- Replace "NAME:" by nothing.

```
String cleaned = myString.replace("NAME:", "");
```

Split the string (as shown in the other answer).

Cut the string (if it always starts with NAME: which length is 5):

```
String cleaned = myString.subString(5);
```

Use a regular expression

Probably 200 other ways.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use something like:

```
String arr[] = myString.Split(":");
String name = arr[1];
```

arr[] will contain 2 elements (0 and 1).
arr[0] will contain "Name"
and
arr[1] will contain the second part (the name itself)

Another version of the same (1 line only):

```
String name = myString.Split(":")[1];
```

Comment: `String arr[] = myString.Split(":", 2);` might be safer in this instance in case there are any wanted `:` in the second half of the String.

Answer (score 0):

Use split method :

```
String name = tmpStr.split(":")[tmpStr.split(":").length-1] ;
```

Comment: This is an overkill... you use the split function twice! And it's also hardly readable. Look at this version: **String name = myString.Split(":")[1];**